# Launching a Silverlight app from another or embeeding one?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I have been tasked with a project which will entail multiple apps, a master apps which will launch child apps.

Is there a way to launch another SL application from with a SL application? or embed a SL app within another?

OR

Am I barking up the working tree, and should I just have the apps as one.

The reasoning for multiple apps is thats what the architect has given as the outline.

hanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having a single application will keep the app coherant feeling to the user, as well as ease development.

Typically, the goal with this type of architecture is to prevent loading of XAPs unnecessarily in order to reduce memory/bandwidth consumption.

If this is the case, I would recommend rethinking the architecture, and using something like MEF.  This allows automatic discovery and loading of XAPs from the server, while still keeping the application as a single application.

Here's a [blog post showing the basic ideas](http://www.davidezordan.net/blog/?p=1734).

Comment: The application will be run locally so bandwidth from loading isnt an issue. I will have to have futher discussions with the architect team. Thanks for the advice.